# Baposter title out of bounds

Tags: baposter

My poster is made using `\baposter`. I changed `fontscale=0.2` and now the title is out of bounds of the poster. How can I move down the boxes to make room for the title or force the title down to compress the boxes?
Note: my title is made using `\textsc`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: To the close voters, please give him some time to provide the MWE.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. Used `headerheight=0.3\textheight` to space the title